# Command line software which returns image descriptions

Tags: gratis, images, ubuntu, command-line, computer-vision

I have a lot of images and I search a very specific one. The file name is probably not meaningful, I only know it's a jpg image (I have 25000 on my PC). I have no idea about when the picture was taken / edited. I only know what is on it (snow, trees, a castle).

Is there an offline command line software which takes the path to an image and returns a description (not necessarily sentences, but a list of words)?

I know this is possible and if nobody else did so I will create it.

Comment: Please note that I'm not interested in any GUI thing.

Comment: maybe,just maybe you could upload all your pics to google.  Then maybe you could leverage the google API via PHP,python, or etc to search for objects from the command line.  Facial,recognition is hard, and object is even harder.

Comment: @cybernard I am not going to upload several GB of (partially personal) data to Google (or any other service which might make use of the images elsewhere / create a profile of me).

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called an image classifier - these are very advanced AI projects that require lots of training and as Google recently and notoriously found tend to be error prone.

[image]

You can potentially build your own using [python](https://www.python.org/), [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) and [SciKit-Learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/) and it will be callable from the command line and should do exactly what you need **but** expect that it will take considerable time to build and train and it will still give some false results - both positive and negative - e.g. was that snow or a sheet of paper.

It will probably be quicker, *if less satisfying*, to run through your images, in batches, with one of the GUI image cataloguing tools applying the tags that you are interested in.  Some insert the tags into the EXIF information of the actual image itself, *which can then be searched for from the command line using ExifTool*, while others store the information about the images in some sort of database some of which are directly accessible from the command line, which is which would be the subject for another question.

Comment: Currently, this is not an answer. I know that I can built this myself as I'm doing research in Computer Vision / neural networks. My question was if somebody else has already built it and made it publicly available (ready to run) or if I have to build it myself.

Comment: As noted above Google have already built something similar but you either have to buy it or upload all of your photos and it is on-line only.